# Binding to ListBoxItem's ActualWidth

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, actualwidth

I have a `ListBox`, which is basically a canvas. The items shall be displayed as `Rectangles`. The position of the rectangles are bound to the items' data via the `ListBoxItem's` `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Right` property.

This is the `ListBox'` `Template`, which generates the `Canvas`:

```
<ListBox.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ListBox.Template>
```

The `ListBox'` `ItemContainerStyle` sets the position of the items:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ...}">
                ...
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Right">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ...}">
                ...
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This actually works. When I surround the `ContentPresenter` with a border, the border has the correct position and size.

Now, the rectangle's `Width` should equal the `ListBoxItem's` actual width. So the `ItemTemplate` looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Rectangle Height="..." 
       Width="{Binding ActualWidth,
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" 
       Fill="..."/>
</DataTemplate>
```

But with this binding applied, the rectangle is never displayed. When I set a constant width, everything renders correctly.

Is there a way to set the rectangle's position within the `Canvas`?

### Update

Using the WPF Tree Visualizer I realized that this is probably a problem of the `ContentPresenter's` `ActualWidth`. The following screenshot shows that the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Right` property are set correctly:
[image: Screenshot of Tree Visualizer]

However, the `ActualWidth` property is set to 4 (the `StrokeThickness` of the contained `Rectangle` is 4). How can this layout problem be solved?

Furthermore, I have to amend my statement of above. Surrounding the `ContentPresenter` with a `Border` does not produce a correct result. Instead, the entire layout seems corrupt.

### Update 2

The MSDN says the following:

> The Canvas.Right offset of a child element does not affect the size of a parent Canvas.
>
> If you specify them, the attached properties Canvas.Top or Canvas.Left take priority over Canvas.Bottom or Canvas.Right properties

So it seems that I have to specify the width explicitly, which should be a minor problem with an appropriate converter.

Comment: Any reason why you're using a Canvas and not a Grid? Canvas is almost always the wrong choice in WPF as its defeat the layout system (unless you really need free positioning that can't be achieved with margins).

Comment: Good point. Meanwhile, it is really not necessary to use a canvas because the scenario has changed slightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the question, it is not possible to define a control's  size only with the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Right` properties.

The wanted behaviour could be achieved with a converter like the following (error handling omitted):

```
public class CanvasWidthConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var canvasLeft = (double)values[0];
        var canvasRight = (double)values[1];

        return canvasRight - canvasLeft;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Use (add the converter as a resource):

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding LeftValue}"/>
    <Setter Property="Width">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CanvasWidthConverter}">
                <Binding Path="LeftValue"/>
                <Binding Path="RightValue"/>
            </MultiBinding>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can do this much more easily as follows:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="..."/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="..."/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Secondly, `Rectangle` does not size to its host control. It's likely you just want to use a `Border` with a `Background` and/or `BorderThickness`&`BorderBrush` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A `Border` seems to be more appropriate, indeed. However, I narrowed down the problem to the layouting system, which exists regardless of the used control. Could you take a look at the updated question?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed something was *in* your `Border`. Since you're in a `Canvas`, the `Border` is basically given the space it asks for, and since it has nothing in it, it won't ask for any space. Put something in your `Border`, like a `TextBlock` with some hard-coded text and you'll then see your items.